# C# WPF window binding to Windows Service events

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, windows-services

Continuing on my previous post found here, [C# Windows Service Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44274894/c-sharp-windows-service-events?noredirect=1#comment75557415_44274894)
I cannot seem to get my windows application to fire events off. I figure it has something to do with these lines of code here.

```
SignalRService.SignalRService.NewMessage += SignalRService_NewMessage;
SignalRService.SignalRService.Connected += SignalRService_Connected;
```

Now I am using this namespace because my windows service and my wpf app are inside the same project. My theory is that because my service is installed onto windows I need to do something more than just call it's namespace in a shared project. I am new to windows services can I be shown the proper way here.

Answer (score 1):

based on your two posts :

- you must not put the namespace when using class, add a "using" in the cs header : SignalRService.SignalRService.xxx ==> using SignalRService;
- do not use the same name for classes and namespace; confusing !
- if you want to easily debug a windows service, put your code in a separated class "signalHub" that will be used in an empty ServiceBase and in a console program, so you don't have to install your service in debug mode
- you must not use the SignalRService in the MainWindow ! just use a signalR client and connect to an url